# Can't set up binding | MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

I'm developing a page that has a Collection View. Inside CollectionView.Footer, when I click on the button, I need to bind to Some Command, but I can't do it, because now there is a binding to SomeModel. Please tell me how to set up binding to ViewModel in CollectionView.Footer

**.xaml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Paraglider.MobileApp.ViewModels"
    xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Paraglider.MobileApp.Models"
    x:Class="Paraglider.MobileApp.Pages.SomePage"
    x:DataType="viewmodels:SomePageViewModel">

    <Grid>

        ...        

        <CollectionView
            Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            SelectionMode="None">

            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                ...
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:SomeModel">
                    ...
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

            <CollectionView.Footer>
                <Border 
                    Margin="10, 0"
                    Padding="10"
                    Stroke="Transparent"
                    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 15,15,15,15">

                    <Border.Shadow>
                        <Shadow Brush="Black" Opacity="0.1" Radius="5" />
                    </Border.Shadow>

                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        
                        ...
                   
                        <Button 
                            Padding="0"
                            CornerRadius="10"
                            HeightRequest="35" WidthRequest="60"
                            BackgroundColor="#FF8787" 
                            FontFamily="geometria_medium" FontSize="24"
                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                            Text="+"
                            Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"/>

                    </StackLayout>

                </Border>
            </CollectionView.Footer>
                                
        </CollectionView>

    </Grid>
      
</ContentPage>
```

**.xaml.cs:**

```cs
using Paraglider.MobileApp.ViewModels;

namespace Paraglider.MobileApp.Pages;

public partial class SomePage : ContentPage
{
    public SomePage (SomePageViewModel viewModel)
    {
        BindingContext = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**viewmodel.cs:**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using Paraglider.MobileApp.Infrastructure.Abstractions;
using Paraglider.MobileApp.Models;
using Paraglider.MobileApp.Services;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Paraglider.MobileApp.ViewModels;

public partial class SomePageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    #region services

    private readonly SomeService someService;

    #endregion

    #region fields

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<SomeModel> someModels;

    #endregion

    public SomePageViewModel(SomeService someService)
    {
        this.someService= someService;
        InitAsync();
    }

    public override async void InitAsync()
    {
        var someModels = await someService.GetAsync() ?? new();
        SomeModels = new ObservableCollection<SomeModels>(components);
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task SomeAsync()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That's strange, considering that the Footer is not in the same part of the view hierarchy. Try this anyway: `Command="{Binding SomeCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:SomePageViewModel}}}"`

Comment: You need to fix your code. InitializeComponents is called first. Before anything else. And do not block View construction. Everything should be done, with commanding and proper events that indicate changes. Page constructs, displays itself, displays loading indicator, the services do some work, the page displays the content and/or errors.

Comment: The thing that jumps out to me in the SomePageViewModel above, is that nowhere is there a SomeCommad exposed. I do not know if this command is exposed in SomeService or elsewhere; but unless there a public ICommand declared in the SomePageViewModel , nothing will happen.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I do agree with @H.A.H. with regards to the organization of your code. You shouldn't set the `BindingContext` before calling `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: @DevenCC The OP is using MVVM Source Generators, the Command is auto-generated with the `[RelayCommand]` attribute: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/overview

Comment: @ewerspej Oh wow, I didn't know about RelayCommand attribute, that's nice and saves a lot of "boilerplate" code, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: There's a lot more, I'm currently writing a blog series about it, if you're interested: https://ewerspej.hashnode.dev/series/mvvm-goodness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure that you can bind correctly to `SomeCommand`, you can use a `RelativeSource` for the binding and refer to the `SomePageViewModel`:

```xml
<Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:SomePageViewModel}}}" />
```

You can also browse the documentation on [relative bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings) and [compiled bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings).